# How to get angle,coords and scale of the object by group?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

in fabricjs,the object's left,top,angle,scaleX and scaleY is different in a group and not in a group.I can get the right attributes based on canvas when a object is not in a group.but once this object is in a group,the left or top or angle I get is based on group.

if I rotate a group,the angle of the group has changed but when I use `group._objects[i].angle`to get the angle of the object,the angle doesn't changed.

[How to get the canvas-relative position of an object that is in a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829475/how-to-get-the-canvas-relative-position-of-an-object-that-is-in-a-group)
this question solved the left top problem,but how to get the angle and the scale by group?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4):

Recently fabricjs got an overhaul of group transformation management.
Use latest version and try this:

```
//object is your desired object inside the group.
var matrix = object.calcTransformMatrix(),
    options = fabric.util.qrDecompose(matrix);
//options will be an object with following properties.
/*
  options.translateX //left position
  options.translateY //top position
  options.scaleX
  options.scaleY
  options.skewX
  options.skewY
  options.angle // angle in degrees.
*/
```

This code is taken from the function `realizeTransform` in fabric.Group class.

Comment: Thanks a lot,but If I want the right result,I have to set object's originX and originY to 'center'. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kzh7agh7/1/. And I don't know why the geometry's default value of originX or Y is 'left' and 'top'.but the Path or Group is 'center'?Why don't make their default values all 'center'?