# How to left align objects in a group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am new to fabric js. i am trying to left align all the objects in a group by using this function.

```js
$rootScope.alignLeft = function () {
    var activeObject = canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.getActiveObject();
    if (activeObject.type == "group") {
        var items = activeObject._objects;
        var left = activeObject.getLeft();
        var top = activeObject.getTop();
        console.log(activeObject);
        canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.remove(activeObject);
        console.log(left);
        console.log(top);
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.add(items[i].set({left: activeObject.left}));
        }

        canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.renderAll();
    }
};
```

The problems that i am facing are

1)if i dont use `.remove(activeGroup)` it makes a duplicate of the objects in the group. I want to keep the activeGroup and somehow stop it from duplicating itself.

2) The `items[i].set({left : activeObject.left}` correctly sets the left alignment but the objects top value changes and i don't want that. i have tried to use `items[i].set({left : activeObject.left,top:activeObject.top});` but failed to keep it constant.

How can i achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i was able to solve these problems. I am sure future newbie's to fabricjs like me will face these basic conceptual problems just like me.

**Answers to points 1&2:**

**1)** I used .remove(activeGroup) to remove it and made a new group and added items inside activeGroup into group.

**2)** Here are some links that really helped me understand the positioning system used in fabricjs  [stackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829475/how-to-get-the-canvas-relative-position-of-an-object-that-is-in-a-group)  [Github link](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/801)

```js
$rootScope.alignLeft = function(){
            

            var activeObject = canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.getActiveObject();
            var group = new fabric.Group();
            if(activeObject.type=="group"){
                var items = activeObject._objects;
                canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.remove(activeObject);
                for(var i = 0;i<items.length;i++){
                    var ObjTop = activeObject.top + items[i].top + activeObject.height/2 ;
                    items[i].set({left :activeObject.left,top:ObjTop});
                    group.addWithUpdate(activeObject.item(i));

                }
                canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.add(group);
                canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.setActiveObject(group);
                canvas.pages[canvas.activePageIndex].fabric.renderAll();

            }


        }
```